# Google Maps pass lat and long from InfoWindow to URL

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this google map that passes the lat and long just fine in other versions.  This version works displaying the marker just fine, which means within the map those value exist.  However, when I click the map_more_button.png it doesn't send the link to the url specified.

Here's the working version:

http://goodnite.jp/tokyo/map/android_map_mobile.html

Here's the map that needs updating:

http://goodnite.jp/tokyo/map/android_map_mobile_single.html

Here's the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <!--<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>-->
    <meta http-equiv = "content-type" content = "text/html; charset = UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <!-- this is the part responsible for hidding the bottom bar -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

<title>GOODNITE TOKYO ~ Locations Map (MOBILE)</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

    var map ;

     var customIcons = {
  club: {
    icon: 'http://goodnite.jp/tokyo/map/marker_small_club.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  bar: {
    icon: 'http://goodnite.jp/tokyo/map/marker_small_bar.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  karaoke: {
    icon: 'http://goodnite.jp/tokyo/map/marker_small_karaoke.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  }
};

    var styles = [{"stylers": [{ "invert_lightness": true }]}];

function load() {
        //hideAddressBar();
        var name ="";      
    var address = "";
    var type = "";
    var lat = "0.0";
    var lng = "0.0";

        var Url=window.location.href;//如果想获取框架顶部的url可以用 top.window.location.href
        var u,g,StrBack='';
        if(arguments[arguments.length-1]=="#")
        u=Url.split("#");
        else
        u=Url.split("?");
        if (u.length==1) g='';
        else g=u[1];

        if(g!=''){
        var gg=g.split("&");
        var MaxI=gg.length;
        str = "lat=";
        //for(xm=0;xm<MaxI;xm++){
    if(gg[0].indexOf(str)==0) {
        lat=gg[0].replace(str,"");
    }

    str="lng="
    if(gg[1].indexOf(str)==0) {
        lng=gg[1].replace(str,"");
    }

    str="name="
    if(gg[2].indexOf(str)==0) {
        name=decodeURI(gg[2].replace(str,""));
    }

    str="address="
    if(gg[3].indexOf(str)==0) {
        address=decodeURI(gg[3].replace(str,""));
    }

    str="type="
    if(gg[4].indexOf(str)==0) {
        type=gg[4].replace(str,"");
    }
    //}
        }

        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng));

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: point,
    zoom: 17,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,{name: "Styled Map"});
    map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
    map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

    //var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br><span id='move_span'><a href='javascript:proMoreShow();'><img src='http://goodnitetokyo.com/mobile/images/map_more_button.png' width='48' height='16' /></a></span><span id='more_info' style='display:none;'>LAT: "+lat+"   >LNG: "+lng+"</span>";


    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br/><a href='javascript:directionsClick(\"" + point.toUrlValue() + "\");'><img src='http://goodnite.jp/tokyo/mobile/images/map_more_button.png' width='48' height='16' /></a>";

    var icon = customIcons[type] || {};

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    icon: icon.icon,
    shadow: icon.shadow
    });


    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
        }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
 }

function doNothing() {}

//var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br/><a href='javascript:directionsClick(\"" + point.toUrlValue() + "\");'><img src='http://goodnite.jp/tokyo/mobile/images/map_more_button.png' width='48' height='16' /></a>";

 function directionsClick(latlng){
    var myURL = 'https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=&daddr=' + latlng + '&sensor=TRUE';
    //var myURL = 'comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=' + latlng + '&sensor=TRUE';
    //var myURL = 'geo:' + latlng + '?z=15';
    window.open(myURL,"_blank");
}


  function hideAddressBar()
  {

    if(!window.location.hash)
        {
    if(document.height < window.outerHeight)
    {
        document.body.style.height = (window.outerHeight + 50) + 'px';
    }
    setTimeout( function(){ window.scrollTo(0, 1); }, 50 );
    }

    };
}
function proMoreShow()
    {
        $("#move_span").css({display:"none"});
        $("#more_info").css({display:"block"});
    }   
  </script>

  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  </head>

  <body onLoad="load()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does some value need to be return, stored or something to properly pass it to the button?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkzVN/1/) from your example

I found the following problems with the Javascript you posted:

a. There was no closing bracket } for the load() function so I modified the code as follows:

```
    ...
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
}
```

b. The `hideAddressBar()` function was badly defined (it had an extra `};`). I removed this so the function is:

```
function hideAddressBar() {
    if (!window.location.hash) {
        if (document.height < window.outerHeight) {
            document.body.style.height = (window.outerHeight + 50) + 'px';
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.scrollTo(0, 1);
        }, 50);
    }
}
```

The full code is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <!--<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>-->
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset = UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <!-- this is the part responsible for hidding the bottom bar -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <title>GOODNITE TOKYO ~ Locations Map (MOBILE)</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[

        var map;

        var customIcons = {
            club: {
                icon: 'http://goodnite.jp/tokyo/map/marker_small_club.png',
                shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            bar: {
                icon: 'http://goodnite.jp/tokyo/map/marker_small_bar.png',
                shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            karaoke: {
                icon: 'http://goodnite.jp/tokyo/map/marker_small_karaoke.png',
                shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            }
        };

        var styles = [{
            "stylers": [{
                "invert_lightness": true
            }]
        }];

        function load() {
            //hideAddressBar();
            var name = "";
            var address = "";
            var type = "";
            var lat = "0.0";
            var lng = "0.0";

            var Url = window.location.href; //??????????url??? top.window.location.href
            var u, g, StrBack = '';
            if (arguments[arguments.length - 1] == "#") u = Url.split("#");
            else u = Url.split("?");
            if (u.length == 1) g = '';
            else g = u[1];

            if (g != '') {
                var gg = g.split("&");
                var MaxI = gg.length;
                str = "lat=";
                //for(xm=0;xm<MaxI;xm++){
                if (gg[0].indexOf(str) == 0) {
                    lat = gg[0].replace(str, "");
                }

                str = "lng="
                if (gg[1].indexOf(str) == 0) {
                    lng = gg[1].replace(str, "");
                }

                str = "name="
                if (gg[2].indexOf(str) == 0) {
                    name = decodeURI(gg[2].replace(str, ""));
                }

                str = "address="
                if (gg[3].indexOf(str) == 0) {
                    address = decodeURI(gg[3].replace(str, ""));
                }

                str = "type="
                if (gg[4].indexOf(str) == 0) {
                    type = gg[4].replace(str, "");
                }
                //}
            }

            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng));

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                center: point,
                zoom: 17,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {
                name: "Styled Map"
            });
            map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
            map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

            //var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br><span id='move_span'><a href='javascript:proMoreShow();'><img src='http://goodnitetokyo.com/mobile/images/map_more_button.png' width='48' height='16' /></a></span><span id='more_info' style='display:none;'>LAT: "+lat+"   >LNG: "+lng+"</span>";


            var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br/><a href='javascript:directionsClick(\"" + point.toUrlValue() + "\");'><img src='http://goodnite.jp/tokyo/mobile/images/map_more_button.png' width='48' height='16' /></a>";

            var icon = customIcons[type] || {};

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: icon.icon,
                shadow: icon.shadow
            });


            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }

        function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(html);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }

        function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;

            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4) {
                    request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                    callback(request, request.status);
                }
            };

            request.open('GET', url, true);
            request.send(null);
        }

        function doNothing() {}

        //var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br/><a href='javascript:directionsClick(\"" + point.toUrlValue() + "\");'><img src='http://goodnite.jp/tokyo/mobile/images/map_more_button.png' width='48' height='16' /></a>";

        function directionsClick(latlng) {
            var myURL = 'https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=&daddr=' + latlng + '&sensor=TRUE';
            //var myURL = 'comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=' + latlng + '&sensor=TRUE';
            //var myURL = 'geo:' + latlng + '?z=15';
            window.open(myURL, "_blank");
        }


        function hideAddressBar() {

            if (!window.location.hash) {
                if (document.height < window.outerHeight) {
                    document.body.style.height = (window.outerHeight + 50) + 'px';
                }
                setTimeout(function() {
                    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
                }, 50);
            }

        }

        function proMoreShow() {
            $("#move_span").css({
                display: "none"
            });
            $("#more_info").css({
                display: "block"
            });
        }
    </script>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body onLoad="load()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OMG, thank you. Looked at it a million times, but I overlooked that.  Works like a charm!